# Newrelic for python to trace all of functions

Tags: newrelic

I have python newrelic agent for my python service. I configured everything using the newrelic.ini file. Now I want to see a trace for all the functions that run on my service.

I see the option `transaction_tracer.function_trace` there but from the explanation in the file it seems like I have to specify each function individuality, which is too hard to maintain. is there a way to set it or other config so that all of the functions will be traced?

How its looking in my python service:
[image]
Part of how its looking in the java service and my goal for the python service:
[image]

Comment: can someone please explain why the -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a metaclass to all of my classes that uses the decorator trace_function on all of the class functions.

```
from types import FunctionType

import newrelic.agent


class TraceClassFunctionsMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, class_name: str, bases: tuple, class_attributes: dict):
        for attr_name, attr_value in class_attributes.items():
            if isinstance(attr_value, FunctionType) and attr_name != '__init__':
                class_attributes[attr_name] = newrelic.agent.FunctionTraceWrapper(attr_value)
        return super(TraceClassFunctionsMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, class_name, bases, class_attributes)
```

Usage:

```
class ExampleClass(metaclass=TraceClassFunctionsMetaclass):
    pass
```